# How to eliminate dead code elimination in React using only Gulp and Browserify?

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify, production

I try to build my React project with gulpfile.js in production mode so the query developer tools show green color in browser tab. However, it still failed with dead code elimination error, which means development version is still detected in react developer tools.

I have already tried many ways to eliminate this error. One of the closest solution is to add 'unreachable-branch-transform' and gulpif argv in browserify part in gulpfile.js. Please check gulpfile.js content below.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');

var argv = require('yargs').argv;
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');

var browserify = require('browserify');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var babelify = require('babelify');

var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var envify = require('envify/custom');

var replace = require('gulp-replace');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var uglifyCSS = require('gulp-uglifycss');
var uglifyJS = require('gulp-uglify');
var version_append = require('gulp-version-append');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');
var historyApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

var workboxBuild = require('workbox-build');

var prefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss'); 
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var chalk = require("chalk");
var path = require('path');

var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var paths = {
            public_view_src : "view/",
            public_view_dest : "public/",
            images: 'img/**/*',
            css :
                    [
                        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                        "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
                        "node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css",
                        "node_modules/lato-font/css/lato-font.min.css"
                    ],
            js :
                {
                    plugins: [
                        "node_modules/clientjs/dist/client.min.js",
                        "node_modules/jquery.payment/lib/jquery.payment.min.js"
                    ],
                    vendor: [
                        "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                    ],
                    react : ["./src/app.js", "./src/**/*.js"],
                    app: "./script/*.js",
                    register_service_worker: 'service_worker/register_service_worker.js'
                },
            fonts : [
                "node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/**/*",
                "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/**/*"
            ],
            less : ["less/style.less", "less/**/*.less", "node_modules/roboto-fontface-pre-css/css/roboto-fontface.less"],
            service_worker: 'service_worker/service-worker.js'
};

function build_service_worker() {
    console.info('Workbox libraries copying started.');
    return workboxBuild.copyWorkboxLibraries(paths.public_view_dest).then((workboxDirectoryName) => {
        console.info('Workbox libraries copied to: ' + workboxDirectoryName);
        return workboxBuild.injectManifest({
            swSrc: `${paths.service_worker}`,
            swDest: `${paths.public_view_dest}/service-worker.js`,
            maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 50000000,
            globDirectory: paths.public_view_dest,
            globPatterns: ['**\/*.{html,js,css,png,svg,otf,ttf,eot,woff,woff2}'],
            globIgnores: ['service-worker.js', 'manifest.json'].concat([`**/workbox*/*.js*`])
        }).then((result) => {
            result.warnings.forEach(console.warn);
            console.info(`${result.count} files will be precached, totaling ${result.size} bytes.`);
            console.info(`import ${paths.public_view_dest}${workboxDirectoryName}/workbox-sw.js to service-worker-script`);
            gulp.src(`${paths.public_view_dest}/service-worker.js`)
            .pipe(replace('#workbox-sw', `${workboxDirectoryName}/workbox-sw.js`))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.public_view_dest));

            console.info('Service worker generation completed.');
        });
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.warn('Workbox lbraries copying failed: ' + error);
    });
}

// map error
function map_error(err) {
    if (err.fileName) {
        gutil.log(chalk.red(err.name)
            + ': '
            + chalk.yellow(err.fileName.replace(__dirname, ''))
            + ': '
            + 'Line '
            + chalk.magenta(err.lineNumber)
            + ' & '
            + 'Column '
            + chalk.magenta(err.columnNumber || err.column)
            + ': '
            + chalk.blue(err.description));
    } else {
        var message = err.message.replace(__dirname + "/", "");

        gutil.log(chalk.red(err.name)
            + ': '
            + chalk.yellow(message));
    }

    this.emit('end');
}

function prevent_cache_assets(){
    return function(){
        return gulp.src(path.join(__dirname, paths.public_view_src + '*.html'))
        .pipe(version_append(['html', 'js', 'css'],
            {
                appendType: 'timestamp', 
                versionFile: 'version.json'
            }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.public_view_dest));
    };
}

function reactScript(watch) {
    var bundler, rebundle;
    bundler = browserify(paths.js.react[0], {
        basedir: __dirname, 
        // debug: watch, 
        cache: {}, // required for watchify
        packageCache: {}, // required for watchify
        fullPaths: watch, // required to be true only for watchify
        debug: argv.production ? false : true
    });

    if(watch) {
        bundler = watchify(bundler);
    }

    bundler.transform('unreachable-branch-transform', { 
        global: true 
    });
    bundler.transform(envify({
        _: 'purge',
        MODE: process.env.MODE
    }));
    bundler.transform(babelify.configure({
        "plugins": ["object-assign"]
    }));


    rebundle = function() {
        console.log("packing react");

        var stream = bundler.bundle();
        stream.on('error', map_error);
        stream = stream.pipe(source('app.min.js'));

        if(!watch) {
            stream = stream.pipe(gulpif(argv.production, buffer()));
            //stream = stream.pipe(uglifyJS());
        }

        return stream.pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/dist'));
    };

    bundler.on('update', rebundle);
    bundler.on('log', gutil.log);

    return rebundle();
}

function es(){
  return gulp.src('public/assets/dist/app.min.js')
    .pipe(uglifyJS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/dist'));
}
 
gulp.task('mini', es);

// task for stage or production
gulp.task('min', ['js', 'vendor', 'less', 'copyfonts', 'prevent_cache_assets']);

// init task
gulp.task('init', ['js', 'vendor', 'less', 'copyfonts', 'watch', 'prevent_cache_assets'], function () {
    gulp.watch([paths.public_view_src + '**\/*', paths.service_worker, paths.public_view_dest + 'assets/**\/*.{html,js,css,png,svg,otf,ttf,eot,woff,woff2}'], ['build-service-worker']);
    return build_service_worker();
});

// imagemin
gulp.task('clean-images-dest', function(){
    return gulp.src('public/assets/img', {read: false})
                .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('images', ['clean-images-dest'], function(){
    return gulp.src(paths.images)
                .pipe(imagemin())
                .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/img'));
});

// react 
gulp.task('react', function () {
    return reactScript(false);
});

// copy fontawesome fonts task
gulp.task('copyfonts', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.fonts)
        .on('error', map_error)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css/fonts'));
});

// less task
gulp.task('less', ['images'], function(){
    var l = less();

    l.on('error', map_error);

    return gulp.src(paths.less[0])
        .pipe(l)
            .pipe(postcss([prefixer({ browsers: ["> 0%"] })]))
        .pipe(uglifyCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css'));
});

// copy lato fonts
gulp.task('cp-myriad-font', function(){
    return gulp.src(['./node_modules/myriad-font/fonts/myriad/myriad-set-pro_text.woff', './node_modules/myriad-font/fonts/myriad/myriad-set-pro_bold.woff'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css/fonts'));
});

// vendor task
gulp.task('vendor', ['cp-myriad-font'], function(){
    return gulp.src(paths.css)
        .on('error', map_error)
        .pipe(concat('vendor.css'))
        .pipe(uglifyCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css/vendor'));
});

// prevent cache task
gulp.task('prevent_cache_assets', prevent_cache_assets());

// javascript task
gulp.task('js', ['js_vendor', 'js_plugins', 'js_register_service_worker'], function(){
    return gulp.src(paths.js.app) 
        .on('error', map_error)
        .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglifyJS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/js'));
});

gulp.task('js_vendor', function(){
    return gulp.src(paths.js.vendor)
            .on('error', map_error)
            .pipe(concat('vendor.min.js'))
            .pipe(uglifyJS())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/js'));
});

gulp.task('js_plugins', function(){
    return gulp.src(paths.js.plugins)
            .on('error', map_error)
            .pipe(concat('plugins.min.js'))
            .pipe(uglifyJS())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/js'));
});

gulp.task('js_register_service_worker', function(){
    return gulp.src(paths.js.register_service_worker)
            .on('error', map_error)
            .pipe(concat('register_service_worker.min.js'))
            .pipe(uglifyJS())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/js'));
});

// task to run api
gulp.task('api', function(cb){
    exec('cd ../mp-wallet-api && nodemon', function(err, stdout, stderr){
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        cb(err);
    });
});

// watcher
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(paths.less, ['less']);
    gulp.watch(paths.js.app, ['js']);
    gulp.watch(paths.js.plugins, ['js']);
    gulp.watch(paths.js.vendor, ['js']);
    gulp.watch(paths.js.register_service_worker, ['js']);
    gulp.watch(paths.css, ['vendor']);
    gulp.watch(paths.fonts, ['copyfonts']);
    gulp.watch(paths.public_view_src + '*.html', ['prevent_cache_assets']);
    
    return reactScript(true);
});

gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
    port: 3000,
    root: [paths.public_view_dest],
    middleware: function(connect, opt){
        return [historyApiFallback({})];
    },
    fallback: 'index.html'
  });
  connect.serverClose();
});

gulp.task('set-production-env', function() {
    return process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
});

gulp.task('default', ['set-production-env', 'init']);
gulp.task('serve', ['set-production-env', 'init', 'connect']);
gulp.task('with-api', ['set-production-env', 'api', 'init']);
gulp.task('build-service-worker', function () {
    return build_service_worker();
});
```

My React project is only using gulp and browserify inside gulpfile.js, so this project doesn't use any build tools listed in documentation link below (grunt, webpack, browserify (standalone),rollup).

https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html

Do you have any suggestion how to eliminate dead code elimination, but only by using gulp and browserify inside it ? Thanks in advance.